# Adding modules to Kernel in LEDE distribution

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, openwrt

So I'm trying to add one of the staging drivers, I'm trying to load FBTFT in the kernel. I'm using this fork  https://github.com/OnionIoT/source

So far things I have done:

`make menuconfig`

and selected the required options

I also configured the kernel to load the staging drivers

`make kernel_menuconfig`

Device drivers -> Graphics support -> Frame buffer Devices

`<*> Support for frame buffer devices`

Device drivers -> Staging drivers

```
<*> Support for small TFT LCD display modules
    <M> FB driver for the ST7735R LCD Controller
    <M> Generic FB driver for TFT LCD displays
    <M> Module to for adding FBTFT devices
```

Then I compile

`make -j5 V=s`

This is the output of the make process [output.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u5zy8027t1psuc1/output.txt?dl=0)

I flash my device with the bin generated.

`sysupgrade -n lede-ramips-mt7688-omega2p-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin`

But when is time to use the module, it doesn't work, I've tried all of this:

```
insmod fb_defio
insmod fb
insmod fbtft

modeprobe fbtft

fbtft_device
```

and nothing works, I don't think the module is correctly configured, I cannot find it anywhere.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

In make kernel_menuconfig
Go to FBTFT driver and press y,
Right now it is selected for compilation, ('M' symbol in front of FBTFT driver).
Once you press y, <'M' > will change to < *> which means it will get compiled and included in final image.

Comment: Thanks @VivekD, I changed them to <*>, however I can’t still see the module, but I can find at least one driver when I perform a find

root@Omega-:/# find . -name fb\*
./proc/fb
./sys/bus/spi/drivers/fb_st7735r
./sys/bus/platform/drivers/fb_st7735r
And if I do this

root@Omega-:~# insmod fbtft_device
Failed to find fbtft_device. Maybe it is a built in module ?
(fbtft_device = “Module to for adding FBTFT devices” kernel config option)

Comment: Hi @utiq, to list down the built-in modules, use lsmod command and try to verify if your module is present in there or not.

Comment: The same, it doesn't show the module when I do lsmod.
The module *.ko should be in /proc/modules, right?